# Cypress ignoreTestFiles is not ignoring tests

Tags: cypress, minimatch

I'm trying to use `ignoreTestFiles` in cypress so that incomplete tests will not get run in the test suite.

The path to my tests is:

```
C:\Users\userA\IdeaProjects\automated_tests\cypress\integration\ignoredTestFiles
```

In `cypress.json`, I have the following entry:

```
"ignoreTestFiles": "*ignoredTestFiles*"
```

I used Globster to verify the minimatch, and it says its correct. But when I run my tests, these files are not getting ignored.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to specify a match for *files*, so I suggest you to add `*.js` to your expression.

Also, you need to add another `*` to match any sub-directory structure, try this expression instead:

```
"ignoreTestFiles": "**/ignoredTestFiles/*.js"
```

Comment: Where are you putting this directive?

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau in `cypress.json`.

Comment: Now is excludeSpecPattern, they don't use ignoreTestFiles any more

Answer (score 15):

You can also pass `array` like:

```
{
    "ignoreTestFiles": [
        "**/1-getting-started/*.js",
        "**/2-advanced-examples/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Now is excludeSpecPattern, they don't use ignoreTestFiles any more

Answer (score 6):

`ignoreTestFiles` has now been depracated, and replaced by `excludeSpecPattern`:

```
{
    //ignore built-in test files
    excludeSpecPattern: [
        "**/1-getting-started/.*.js",
        "**/2-advanced-examples/.*.js",
    ]
}
```